Easy Overvoltage and Reverse polarity protection circuit
I'm looking for the simplest and most effective way to add an overvoltage and reverse polarity protection network to a signal line connected to an MCU, the maximum allowable voltage at the MCU pin is 4.5V. MY idea is to get a 12V signal down to 4V using a resistive divider and adding a Schottky diode for reverse polarity protection and a TVS for overvoltage. My question is:

Is this the best approach?
How to choose the TVS and Schottky diodes for proper protection?


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Most important is knowing how fast you want the MCU to respond to changes in the input signal. Also, what are the absolute maximum and minimum voltages of the input signal?  Answer these questions first.

Although still not defined but the MCU is expected to have a response in 500ns-1us, the voltage in the input is in the range of 8-13V

404: there is a trade off . It’s easy  to protect the input by using large value resistors, thereby limiting the maximum current.  However, large value resistors will cause the signals to change slowly (due to capacitance in the circuit).  The MCU is fast, of course, but  is it ok that the MCU pin voltage changes slowly, ( like 10 msec, for example)? )
